# Set proper encoding when redirecting PHP stdout to file

Tags: php, character-encoding, command-line-interface

I launch a PHP script from Windows command prompt, redirecting the stdout and stderr to two files. If the PHP script outputs accented characters, they will result in strange symbols in the two files mentioned above.

How to set correct chaset output when redirecting output to files?

I launch the script using:

```
C:\>php myscript.php 2>stderr.log 1>stdout.log
```

Comment: I think you might find some answers [in this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how).

Comment: How exactly are you viewing these files? Maybe only the program that's *reading* the file is getting it wrong?

Comment: no I'm using Notepad++ and I usually read UTF-8 files properly

Comment: I already say the thread but it doesn't work when redirecting output. Also I'm experiencing exactly the same problem on Linux